# Which files (other than Log files) should I need to delete from my SharePoint Front end server in order to free disk space

Tags: sharepoint-server

I want to free up disk space on sharepoint front end server. I have removed the Log files at this path: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS` in order to free up some disk space.

Which other files should I need to delete from my SharePoint Front end server in order to free disk space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually start by finding the hogs on the server using https://windirstat.net/. This app will show you which folder(s) is(are) taking up more space than you expected.
On a web front end I usually move:

1. the SharePoint logs (https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/04/change-log-file-location-diagnostic-uls-trace-log-usage-health-data-collection.html) and
2. the IIS logs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/managing-iis-log-file-storage#move-the-log-folder-to-a-remote-system).
3. Depending on the server role, you might also have large index files (search role). The location depends on your configuration. ([What is the search Index file location?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135394/what-is-the-search-index-file-location))

It is not always a good idea to delete content, you should consider moving it in a different volume.

Finally, I usually realise that the windows updates files are what take up most of the space on the disk (winsxs folder). So, I would also suggest you to check other articles for this: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=windows+server+folder+disk+space